# Roll a die 10 times. What is the probability that the number of ones and sixes equals four?

Tags: probability

Suppose a die is tossed 10 times. Let $X$ be the number of ones and let $Y$ be the number of sixes.

How would you find the probability that $P\left(X+Y=4\right)$?

My attempt so far:

Applying the Binomial Distribution, I can find the probability that $X$ or $Y$ equals $4$, but I do not know how to put these pieces together to find $P\left(X+Y=4\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the probability also in an elementary way as follows:

You are interested in sequences of length $10$ consisting of the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$:

Number of all possible such sequences: $\color{blue}{6^{10}}$

Now for the number of sequences with the sum of occurrences of $1$'s and $6$'s equals $4$:

- number of ways to choose 4 places out of $10$ for $1$'s and $6$'s: $\color{blue}{\binom{10}4}$
- number of possible fillings of these $4$ places with $1$'s and $6$'s: $\color{blue}{2^4}$
- number of ways to fill the remaining $6$ places with the other $4$ numbers: $\color{blue}{4^6}$

All together:

$$P(X+Y=4)= \color{blue}{\frac{\binom{10}4\cdot 2^4\cdot 4^6}{6^{10}}}$$

Or more general for $k=0,\ldots ,10$:

$$P(X+Y=k)=\frac{\binom{10}k\cdot 2^k\cdot 4^{10-k}}{6^{10}}=\binom{10}k\left(\frac 13\right)^{k}\left(\frac 23\right)^{10-k}$$
which corresponds to the other answers using Bernoulli directly.

Answer (score 3):

alternative approach

$E$ is the event of a 1 or a 6

$p(E) = 1/3$.

Let $p = 1/3.$

Let $q = 1 - p$.

General formula for exactly $k$ successes in $n$ tries, where 
$n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and $k \in \{0,1,\cdots, n\}$ is

$$\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}$$

Here, $n=10$ and $k=4.$

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider all the cases, $(X=4,Y=0); (X=3,Y=1); (X=2,Y=2); (X=1,Y=3); (X=0,Y=4).$  There are two pairs that are equal.  Alternately, you can group the sides of the die into the groups of interest:  (1 or 6) with probability $\frac 13$ and something else with probability $\frac 23$ and do the binomial distribution for $4$ of the first case and $6$ of the second.

Comment: Could I use the binomial distribution for each case and then sum those results? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Actually, I was careless; I didn't read your answer closely enough.  If I had, I would have realized that your answer makes mine redundant.